# What is the local variable?

Tags: java, oop, variables, integer

```
class subject {

    private String sub;
    private int marks;
    private double average;

    public subject() {
        sub = "Physics";
        marks = 60;
        average = 79.5;
        int x = 20;
        double y = 30;
    }

    public void change(String a) {
        int z = 10;
        sub = a;
    }

    public String display() {
        int w = 5;
        return sub;
    }
}
```

What are the local variables in this program? are they *int x; double y; int z; int w;*?
or *sub; int z; int w;*?

Comment: Local variables are those defined in a method or constructor.

Comment: I did but I'm kind of confused

Comment: That means they are _int x; double y; int z; int w;_ right?

Comment: Just so you know, Stack Overflow is where you go to ask about specific programming issues, like "I tried to do X, but I got error Y. How do I fix it?" When you're looking for definitions, particularly those regarding Java fundamentals, you look to your learning materials, to your instructors and to tutorials. If you're confused about something, you could at least explain what confuses you. Learning is an art unto itself. If you're going to be any good at programming, that process never ends, so you might as well develop good habits earlier rather than later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare variables inside of the methods and constructor called local variables.

```
public subject() {
    int x = 20;
    double y = 30;
}

 public void change(String a) {
    int z = 10;
}

public String display() {
    int w = 5;
}
```